# CSS3 Parallax Scrolling

Tags: html, css, web, parallax

I am working on a project and need to get a pure css3 parallax scrolling effect working.
It works, but if I put a container around the africaCloud1, africaCloud2 and africaCloud3, it doesnt. I need to create some containers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Parallax Scrolling v2 - Afrika</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <section class="africa">
            <img id="africaCloud1" src="vendor/img/africaCloud1.png" alt="Wolke" />
            <img id="africaCloud2" src="vendor/img/africaCloud2.png" alt="Wolke" />
            <img id="africaCloud3" src="vendor/img/africaCloud3.png" alt="Wolke" />
        </header>
    </section>
</body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/js/app.js"></script>
```

```
html {  
    -webkit-overflow: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    -webkit-overflow: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    background: rgb(147, 151, 183);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(147, 151, 183) 30%, rgb(207, 210, 233) 70%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(147, 151, 183) 30%, rgb(207, 210, 233) 70%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(147, 151, 183) 30%, rgb(207, 210, 233) 70%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(147, 151, 183) 30%, rgb(207, 210, 233) 70%);
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(147, 151, 183) 30%, rgb(207, 210, 233) 70%);
    perspective: 1px;
    height: 100vh;
}

.africa {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 1500px;
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
}

.africa > img {
    position: absolute;
}

#africaCloud1 {
    right: 0px;
    top: -100px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.2);
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.2);
}

#africaCloud2 {
    left: 20%;
    top: -550px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-15px) scale(0.8);
    transform: translateZ(-1.5px) scale(0.8);
}

#africaCloud3 {
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0.5px) scale(1.2);
    transform: translateZ(-0.5px) scale(1.2);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Comment: Yes, I did. I have this site in my bookmarks.

Comment: I read the article again and got a solution. Needed to add  transform-style: preserve-3d; position:relative; to the container. Thanks CZorio!

Answer (score 2):

You close the `header` but you don't open it. Replace this part to that :

```
<body>
    <section class="africa">
        <header>
            <img id="africaCloud1" src="vendor/img/africaCloud1.png" alt="Wolke" />
            <img id="africaCloud2" src="vendor/img/africaCloud2.png" alt="Wolke" />
            <img id="africaCloud3" src="vendor/img/africaCloud3.png" alt="Wolke" />
        </header>
    </section>
</body>
```

Also, this selector `.africa > img` means `img` who are **direct** child of `.africa`. If you add the `header` around the `img`, it won't affect it any more.

Comment: You are right, I already corrected it. Thank you! Its working now, see comments.